# find conditions about vectors of pairs

Tags: c++, vector, find, std-pair

suppose I have a std::vector of pair. How can I use, efficiently, method std::find to see whether at least one element of the vector is not equal to (false, false)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::pair` overloads `operator==`, so you can use `std::find` for the affirmative:

```
bool b = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), std::make_pair(false, false)) == v.end();
```

and you can use `std::find_if` for the negative:

```
bool b = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), 
                      std::bind2nd(std::not_equal_to<std::pair<bool, bool> >(),
                                   std::make_pair(false, false)))
             != v.end();
```

The second one can be written much more cleanly in C++0x:

```
bool b = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), 
                      [](const std::pair<bool, bool> p) { 
                          return p != std::make_pair(false, false);
                      }) != v.end();
```

Comment: I'm sorry I meant to say that I need to check if all the elements are (false, false)

Comment: @Banana: You can use the `find_if` approach and negate the result (if there is no element such that the element is equal to (false, false), then every element must be equal to (false, false)).  Also, C++0x adds `all` and `any` algorithms (or something like them) that make testing that condition much cleaner.

Comment: Your second solution solved my problem, but may be your third solution has error.

Comment: about 10 errors that i think stackoverflow doesn't allow me to  exceed to length of comment.in stl_algo.h